# .NET Code Coverage Monitoring

Tags: code-coverage

There is staging server with multiple .NET web applications deployed. Is there any way to monitor Code Coverage through some tool?

I am trying to expose code coverage to testing team. I know we can have automated unit test cases but in some cases manual test cases required to experiment.

Basically, I want to make sure all modified source files are covered with some scenarios on staging server before testing team sign off for deployment in production.

I am trying to make testers more aware about what is not covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use nuNit tests , i would say use DotCover by JetBrains, NCover , or an open source version is part cover which isnt being added to new features anymore.

I use NCover and I like it, I also toyed with DotCover and its pretty good also.

Apparently NCover 4 has alot of new features where they even have an ide for testers so you can see code coverage and work towards establishing a good base of tests even if you arnt a developer.

Open Cover also has 32 and 64 bit support and is currently being worked on.

https://github.com/sawilde/opencover

http://www.ncover.com/products/home#

http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/

https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4/

Comment: However [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) is still being developed and has 32/64 bit support.

Comment: PartCover is 32-bit(x86) only, I believe the latest NCover handles both